# Java Stream BufferedReader file stream

Tags: java-8, bufferedreader, java-stream

I am using Java 8 Streams to create stream from a csv file.
I am using `BufferedReader.lines()`, I read the docs for `BufferedReader.lines()`:

> After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line.

```
public class Streamy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Reader reader = null;
        BufferedReader breader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader("refined.csv");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        breader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        long l1 = breader.lines().count();
        System.out.println("Line Count " + l1); // this works correctly

        long l2 = breader.lines().count();
        System.out.println("Line Count " + l2); // this gives 0
    }
}
```

It looks like after reading the file for first time, reader does not get to beginning of the file. What is the way around for this problem

Answer (score 8):

> It looks like after reading the file for first time, reader does not get to beginning of the file.

No - and I don't know why you would expect it to given the documentation you quoted. Basically, the `lines()` method doesn't "rewind" the reader before starting, and may not even be able to. (Imagine the `BufferedReader` wraps an `InputStreamReader` which wraps a network connection's `InputStream` - once you've read the data, it's *gone*.)

> What is the way around for this problem

Two options:

- Reopen the file and read it from scratch
- Save the result of `lines()` to a `List<String>`, so that you're then not reading from the file at all the second time. For example:

  ```
  List<String> lines = breader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

As an aside, I'd strongly recommend using `Files.newBufferedReader` instead of `FileReader` - the latter *always* uses the platform default encoding, which isn't generally a good idea.

And for that matter, to load all the lines into a list, you can just use [`Files.readAllLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)... or [`Files.lines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) if you want the lines as a stream rather than a list. (Note the caveats in the comments, however.)

Comment: Reading all the lines into a list can also be done `Files.readAllLines`

Comment: If a stream reading from the beginning is desired [`Files.lines(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) does the whole opening of a reader and converting to a stream. So there is no need to mess around with the `BufferedReader` then.

Comment: Please note that unlike `Files.readAllLines` the underlying reader created with `Files.lines` is not closed automatically until garbage collected, so you should manage the stream as autocloseable if you care about leaking file descriptors. This is actually not much shorter than using `BufferedReader.lines`.

Comment: @TagirValeev: Gosh, that does seem a significant shortcoming. Will need to look into that myself. Will add a caveat in the answer.

Comment: The question’s original code didn’t take much care about resource leakage anyway. In a real-life scenario, using the stream within a `try(…)` isn’t much syntactical overhead and the bigger question is whether reading the entire file into memory as with `readAllLines` is acceptable. Oh, and whether the application logic could get rid of processing the lines twice…

Answer (score 2):

Probably the cited fragment from JavaDoc needs to be clarified. Usually you would expect that after reading the whole file reader will point to the end of the file. But using streams it depends on whether short-circuit terminal operation is used and whether the stream is parallel. For example, if you use

```
String magicLine = breader.lines()
    .filter(str -> str.startsWith("magic"))
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);
```

Your reader will likely to stop after the first found line (because no need to read further) or read the whole input file if such line is not found. If you make the same operation in parallel stream, then the resulting position will be unpredictable, because input will be split to some implementation-dependent chunks where the search will be performed. That's why it's written this way in the documentation.

As for workaround ways, please read the @JonSkeet answer. And consider closing your streams via try-with-resource construct.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific line, why wouldn't you create **two** readers?

```
 reader1=new FileReader("refined.csv");
 reader2=new FileReader("refined.csv");
```